# Box-drawing characters aren't aligned in Xmobar

Tags: utf, xmobar

I've created a little Xmobar status indicator for https://complice.co. Inspired by the agnoster Zsh theme, I used some box-drawing characters to try to put triangle-like ends on the end of the status bar. But they aren't aligning correctly, as shown here:

[image]

The triangle is too small, leaving a lip at the bottom. It annoys me that it's not pixel-perfect. Does anyone have any insight into why it isn't sized correctly? I've never used box-drawing characters and couldn't find any documentation on the specific ones I'm using (`\ue0b2` and `\ue0b0`) - any links would be appreciated.

I use a script to generate the text. The important part is here where I use the box-drawing characters: https://github.com/d4hines/beth/blob/master/scripts/complice#L38

And the Xmobar config: https://github.com/d4hines/beth/blob/master/flake.nix#L249-L265

Comment: `\ue0b2` and `\ue0b0` are characters from _Private Use_ area in Unicode so rendering them strongly depends on used font. Try `FuraMono NF` or `SpaceMono NF`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I installed Nerd Fonts and switched to "FuraCode Nerd Font Mono", but it's not quite right either: https://i.imgur.com/bvORrPg.png

I ended up reversing the direction of the left triangle and for some reason in normal Fira Code it looks OK if I don't stare it super close.